# Dropzone: Uncaught ReferenceError: UploadFilesToServer is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, dropzone

I have a need to allow users to drag and drop file which will be then processed when the user clicks on Upload Files button.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="/" method="post" class="dropzone" id="myAwesomeDropzone" data-previews-container="#file-previews"
                                        data-upload-preview-template="#uploadPreviewTemplate" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                        
                                        
                                        <div class="fallback">
                                            <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="dz-message needsclick">
                                            <i class="h1 text-muted dripicons-cloud-upload"></i>
                                            <h3>Drop files here or click to upload.</h3>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
```

And here is the script that I am using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){                        
        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("#myAwesomeDropzone", {
            autoProcessQueue: false,                
            maxFilesize: 20,  //MB
            addRemoveLinks: true,
            maxFiles: 10, //Limit the number of files user can drag and drop to upload
            url: "/",
        });
                    
        function UploadFilesToServer()
        {                
            var TotalFiles = myDropzone.getQueuedFiles(); //<= this line give error
            console.log(TotalFiles);
            
        } //function UploadFilesToServer()
        
    }); //$(document).ready(function(){
```

When a user clicks on the Button I want to get the number of files and then I want to loop through each file and assign it to an Array.

But I am getting error when I try to get the number of files using **var TotalFiles = myDropzone.getQueuedFiles();** It throws error.

What mistake am I  making here?

Comment: I'm getting a different error: "Dropzone already attached". Removing the `dropzone` class from the div fixes that. Now everything works fine, I'm getting neither of the two unrelated errors you mention in your title and text. https://jsfiddle.net/nzpmexto/

Comment: @ChrisG, even after removing the dropzone class from the div I am getting the same error message.

Comment: You should probably move the function outside the jQuery wrapper. Still, the code worked for me.